# Stripe API Annual subscription

Tags: stripe-payments

Is anyone aware of a way to enter a user into an annual subscription which is paid monthly.

Essentially the customer is agreeing to pay £300 a year spread over 12 months (so 12 payments of £25)

The customer cannot cancel before the 12 month term is over and must give 1 month notice to cancel their plan.

What would be the best way to implement this as I cannot see this as an option in their subscription API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Update a subscription" endpoint takes a [`cancel_at` parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-cancel_at) that sets the subscription to end at a specific date/time.

If your user initiates a cancellation, update it with a `cancel_at` date that's the end of their one year subscription period (or the *next* year's, if they're under the one month notification period).